# Discord app that runs on Python wont work with heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

Someone made a discord bot that runs on Python code but for some reason it wont run on heroku. This is the build/error log that I got.

> -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
>          More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
>    !     Push failed

But I added python as a buildpack (with the menu/application settings from Heroku)

And these are the install instructions for if you want to run the code on your local machine:
[>>Intructions for local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LWHu.png)

Is there anyway to run this on Heroku or is the app just not compatible?

Kind regards,

Ruben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either host your code in Github like this example [here](https://github.com/CharmingMother/git_to_heroku) or upload your file directly from your computer using Heroku's [CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) and [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

After that Go to

`Heroku --> Deploy`

`Under Development Method` Pick `Heroku Git` and it'll have instructions

You'll have to create a file named `requirements.txt` in which you will put the names of the python modules that you want to use which is does not come as a standard part of Python. Second, you'll need a file called `Procfile` without any extensions, inside it decide your dynos. In your case, it will be `worker: python the_file_to_run.py`

I recommend you look at this example [here](https://github.com/CharmingMother/git_to_heroku) in Github to get a better understanding